# How to make some part of the string bold?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display a text on a view, but I want that some parts of the text to be another font type.

So, I have this localised string in my Localizable file :

`"unencrypted_emails_header" = "we may send you **business email unencrypted** and that you assume the risks"`

I want that the text inside the ** **, to be bold. I tried a way but nothing happens, the font is not modified. Also, if I'm only adding ** ** in the text, I can still see the ** ** wrapped around the text.

That's what I tried :

```
Text(headerText())
     .rchFont(.rchBody)

    private func headerText() -> String {
        let rchBodyFont = RCHFont.rchBody
        let rchBodyBoldFont = RCHFont.rchBodyBold
        let headerString = strings.unencryptedEmailsHeader.replacingOccurrences(of: "**", with: "")
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: headerString)
        if let range = headerString.range(of: #"(?<=\*\*)(.*?)(?=\*\*)"#, options: .regularExpression) {
            let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: headerString)
            attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: rchBodyBoldFont, range: nsRange)
        }
        return attributedString.string
    }
```

Minimum iOS target is 15. This method removes the **, but the font is not changed for that specific part of the text. Thanks !

EDIT:
Now is working, but I need to have that type of font for the text, .rchBody and it overrides the the string, so I can not see the bold text anymore. If I don't put a font for the text, is working.

```
   Text(LocalizedStringKey(strings.unencryptedEmailsHeader))
        .rchFont(.rchBody)
```

Comment: What is `rchFont` modifier?

Comment: Is a modifier for changing the font like .font

`func rchFont(_ rchFont: RCHFont, _ color: Color = .textDefault) -> some View`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI supports Markdown natively. No needs for `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
Text("Some **BOLD** text")
```

⚠️ Note that it should **NOT** be `String`. It should be passed to the text as `LocalizedStringKey` or `LocalizedStringResource` for newer iOS versions

Comment: I tried to use that, but on the screen, I see my text : `"we may send you **business email unencrypted** and that you assume the risks"` like it is in the localised file.

Comment: I have added a note about it

Comment: Hei, now is working. But the font overrides the bold from the ** ** in the string so it does not work anymore. If I don't put a font, is working.

See my edit

Comment: It seems that you are overriding the behavior. It's not related to the original question but Please provide more data about the `rchFont` implementation and `rchBody` variations.